# git command - filtering commits while pushing

Tags: git, github

I have made multiple commits but don't want all commits to be pushed for now. Is there a way to push only those commits which I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options,

#### rebase

Say, you want to include 3 out of five most recent commits:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5           # reorder the lines in the text editor, 
                               # leave the 'private' commits at the end
git push origin HEAD~2:master  # push all but the last two
```

#### cherry pick

This involves a temporary branch and is a lot more work

```
git checkout -b temp HEAD~5
git cherrypick <hash1>
git cherrypick <hash2>
git cherrypick <hash3>
git push origin master
```

### Recommendations

- I recommend against cherrypicking since it is more errorprone and easily makes identical commits seem 'unidentical'
- use the `--cherry-pick` or `--cherry-mark options` with `git log` to see the *actual* differences between refs (`git log --cherry-pick --oneline master...origin/master`)

Comment: What if i am in a master branch?

Comment: What does that mean? There are only branches. If you insist: there are _tracking branches_ too (that are also just branches, but configured to push/pull from a specific other branch)

Comment: So it doesn't matter whether if i am in master or other local branch to use above options.

Comment: Not technically, no. It might depend on the _meaning_ of the branch (whether it represents a public version, e.g.): see [RECOVERING FROM AN UPSTREAM REBASE](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html) or the 'easier' [`fixing mistakes` paragraph](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#fixing-mistakes)

Answer (score 1):

This command can help:

```
$ git push origin <thelonghash>:master
```

But if you have commits `A->B->C->D` and do `git push origin C:master` the commits `A,B,` and `C` will be pushed to origin. So if you need push only `C` you need to use `git rebase -i` to
rearrange the commits so that `C` is earliest.